# Add facet to Content editor search - field name with two words not working

Tags: content-editor, content-search

I am trying to add a new facet to the content editor, everything is working fine with single word fields (Ex: Authors, Subjects, locations, etc), but same is not working with **two word fields** (EX: Author Location, or Content Type).

- Used the lower case name of the field, and underscore as the separator, (author_location, content_type)
- Checked the master index, field is present.

Not sure, what i am missing here, and also renamed the two word field, to single word field, then it started working, again changed back to two word field, it is not working.

When two world field name facet is added, default facets are also not working.

Sitecore Version: **8.2 update 2 (rev. 161221)**
Search Engine: **Solr**

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on Sitecore facets documentation : https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/facets

You can specify item field names. When you specify a field name in the Field Name field of the facet item, Sitecore creates a facet based on this field. You can enter multiple field names as a comma-separated list and when you do, Sitecore creates hierarchical filters (for example, belts/black, belts/white, and so on.) **You specify the field name in lower case, and use the name of the field as it is in the index.**
Fields that can have many different values across items are not good candidates for facets, and you should avoid using such fields. For example, a field that has a unique value in each item would cause Sitecore to create a filter for each item.

Please have a look on Author Name default Sitecore facets :

[image]